# MinimumOSVersion error while submitting Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchos-2

I am trying to submit my app, but am seeing this error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90455 "Invalid WatchKit App Bundle. The value '2.1' for the MinimumOSVersion key in info.plist in bundle {redacted}.watchkitapp is not supported"

I have updated Xcode but it still doesn't work.

UPDATE:

[image]

I have always the same error message with your settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set your minimum os version 2.0.Maybe 2.1 is too advanced!

Answer (score 4):

There is a relationship between the iOS version you're supporting on a phone, and watchOS version available for a paired watch.  For example, watchOS 2.1 would not be available with a phone running 9.0.x or 9.1

If you are supporting less recent versions of iOS, please set your minimum watchOS version to 2.0.

You can find this in Project Settings -> Watch App Target -> Build Settings -> (null) - Deployment -> watchOS Deployment Target:

[image]

Comment: I have always the error message :/

Comment: @PenardCorentin If you are still seeing the same error, you must have missed where it is set to 2.1.  In Xcode, search your project for `2.1`.  If you still have issues, clean your build folder, then rebuild, archive, and upload that build to iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3):

Please set  WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 2.0 in Build Settings of Project.

[image]